# Why is this writing to the same line over and over when output to a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I've made a web scraping app that I want to put the data into a csv file. The scraper part works fine and prints to the command line, but when I try to write to a csv it rewrites iteration of the loop data (there's 100) on the first line over and over. I'm not sure why. Any ideas why it isn't writing the results to a new line each time? (I've tried with both csv.writer and csv.DictWriter methods. Same result.)

```
def create_csv_file():
    file_name = str(datetime.date.today())
    field_names = ['Rank', 'Title', 'Author', 'Star Rating', 'Price']
    with open('{}.csv'.format(file_name), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        the_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=field_names)
        the_writer.writeheader()

    return file_name, field_names

def get_book_details(soup, file, headers):
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='zg_itemImmersion')

    for i in items:
        #Web Scrape code here. Cut to truncate.

        with open('{}.csv'.format(file), 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            the_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
            the_writer.writerow({'Rank': rank, 'Title': title, 'Author': author, 'Star Rating': star_rating, 'Price': price})
```

Comment: You're opening the file in write mode (`'w'`) inside a `for` loop - that erases any existing contents of the file on each iteration. Open in append mode. OR open the file once and put the `for` loop inside the context manager (much faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every loop iteration, you close the CSV file, return to the top of the loop, and open the file again.  This returns to the start of the file.  Use `'a'`, append mode if you have to open it each time through the loop.

Alternately, open the file *before* you enter the loop; have your `for` inside the `with` block.

Comment: A lot of things are obvious *after* someone points out which of the 17 factors is the problem.  That's why Stack Overflow exists.